# How to choose target disk for boot-loader during Windows 10/11 installation?

Tags: bootloader, efi, windows-11

I had a Windows 10 and I decided to try Windows 11. My motherboard works in UEFI mode.

I had 2 physical disks on my PC:

- disk 1: here is my current Windows 10 installed
- disk 2: a disk with an unallocated area for installing Windows 11

Both are GPT (do not know if it matters)

I created a bootable USB with the Microsoft media creation tool and used it to begin Windows 11 installation process. I booted from USB and kept both physical hard drives connected.

On installer GUI, I've chosen "Custom install" instead of "Upgrade" option and chosen an unallocated area from disk 2 as a target. I did not see any other options to control the target for Windows 11 (or it's bootloader) installation.

The result is that my PC still boots from disk 1 (disk 2 is not bootable, I can see it when I press F11 on startup). The bootloader on disk 1 offers me to choose if I want to boot an old Windows 10 or freshly installed Windows 11.

Also, after Windows 11 had been installed, an unallocated area on disk 2 became: 1) a 16 Mb "Microsoft reserved partition" + 2) NTFS partition for Windows 11 itself. Seems like there is no place for bootloader on disk 2. I do not know what are those 16 MBs are used for.

If I erase disk 1 (because so far I liked Windows 11 and I want to switch on a clean Windows 11 installation) or physically disconnect it, I won't be able to boot my fresh Windows 11 from Disk 2.

Looks like now I need to reinstall it again (and disconnect disk 1 until I erase Windows 10 from it).

How was I supposed to control where the bootloader for Windows 11 will be installed? Is there an option to change this during Windows installation? If I remember correctly, Linux installers usually give me a choice of target disk for installing bootloader

Comment: That seems like a lot of work. Can you upgrade your Windows 10 machine to Windows 11?  Test it. Then roll back if you do not like it.

Comment: *My bios works in EFI mode* Then it's UEFI, not BIOS. There's no point in keeping using the same name for a technology that has been *de facto* abandoned a decade ago. *The result is...* **Entirely expected!** That's how it should be. With UEFI you don't boot drives, you boot entries (.efi files) from an UEFI partition. Again, this is the standard since 2012 and Windows 8. All bootloaders are saved in said EFI partition irrespective of where the system partitions resides. Only one EFI partition is required per system and only one **should** exist in any given drive.

Comment: The only way to have a second EFI partition in the second drive - again, not needed and NOT recommended - is to (temporarily) disconnect or disable the first one. This however would create an even more confusing state.

Comment: Windows 11 only supports UEFI mode and can ONLY be installed to HDD using GPT instead of MBR.  It's not possible to boot into Windows 11 while Compatibility Mode is enabled to an MBR partition. "I won't be able to boot my fresh Windows 11 from Disk 2." - [Edit] your question to indicate the reason you believe this to be true.  You certainly could delete the Windows partition on DISK 1, keep the EFI partition on DISK 1, and still boot to Windows 11 partition that exists DISK 2.  You could also skip that heart ache and simply upgrade your Windows 10 partition to Windows 11.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I do not understand why it is not recommended to have 2 EFI partitions on 2 different drives and have a freedom to choose where to boot from. This is what I wanted, while I got everything installed to disk 1. Is there a way to control this besides physically disconnecting disk 1 during Windows installation on disk 2?

Comment: @Ramhound did not  get your point about MBR, I have only GPT disks. Yes, I am sure that I am unable to boot from Disk 2. An easy check: disconnect disk 1 physically. Fixed my post. The final goal is to remove disk 1 completely, I can not just erase Windows 10 NTFS partition and be happy with that. But now I am bound to disk 1, because Windows 11 installer reused disk 1 bootloader instead of creating it's own on disk 2

Comment: @Kirill - You seemed confused, since you indicated, you didn't know if GPT mattered or not when it came to Windows 11.

Comment: @Kirill - It's not recommended because you would have to go into the firmware settings to boot to the other installation, instead of simply using the singular Windows Boot Manager, to switch between installations. Why don't you just image the Windows 11 installation on top of the Windows 10 installation then cleanup the EFI partition BCD entries?